# Why is e^-alpha

Tags: bayesian, exponential-distribution

I'm an Education major taking computational statistics. I'm having trouble figuring out how a variable (alpha) distributed as an exponential (lambda = 1) can be expressed as e^-alpha. We're covering the Bayesian approach to estimating densities. My professor's notation is:

> Let us consider the problem of parameterizing the model in a Bayesian framework, and put indepen-
>   dent exponential (marginal) prior distributions upon the parameters: θ = (α, σ):
>
> α ∼ EXP(1) and σ ∼ EXP(1)

Which, in his solutions comes out to be:

$exp(-\alpha \alpha_0)$

Then it's established that $\alpha_0 = 1$:

$exp(-\alpha)$

Which looks a lot like the PDF for the exponential, but $\alpha$ is used as an argument? That is,

$EXP(1) = \lambda exp(-\lambda x)$

let $\lambda = 1$

$EXP(1) = exp(-x)$

let $x = \alpha$ then:

$exp(-\alpha)$

It's the last step I don't understand. I'm guessing it might have something to do with conceptualizing parameters as random variables, but I'm not sure why they would be used as an input to the distribution here.

Comment: Got it! This is because the prior is written:

$\pi(\alpha) \pi(\sigma)$

Thus expanding this notation:

$\pi(x = \alpha; \lambda = 1) \pi(x = \sigma; lambda = 1)$

That's why! My lack of background in stats keeps kicking my butt in weird ways, especially when it comes to notational conventions that math people just "know" from having the undergrad classes. Woo! XD

Comment: If you feel that you know the answer to your question, you can write it in the Answer box